# learning AWS components and tutorials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-dynamodb

My questions says it all, Looking forward to learn about AWS components ,creating instances and may be with screenshots of the website to give more better look,some videos,
Any website that could help me?
I am a quick learner but honestly Amazon website is just full of content with nothing catchy and understandable.

Comment: check http://www.youtube.com/user/AmazonWebServices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your use case is or coding background, but if PHP here's a nice start:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/index.html

Also try YouTube AWS channel as suggested above. The various heads of the web service groups post videos and webinars.